# jQuery onclick event to add Dynamic Tabs for opening view page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i want to open view page in dynamically tabs in jQuery event

my clickable link

```
<li id="btnHtml">
<a href="#">  text </a></li>
```

jQuery code to add dynamically tab and open view page in the tab.

```
  var tabs = $('#tabs').bootstrapDynamicTabs().addTab({
        title: 'Home',
        Url: '/tab/ajax/file.html',
        id: 'ajax',
        ajaxUrl: '/tab/ajax/file.html',
        loadScripts: '/tab/js/load.js',
        loadStyles: ['/tab/css/test.css', '/tab/css/test2.css'],
        active: true,
        allowClose: false
    });

    $('#btnHtml').click(function () {
        tabs.addTab({

            title: 'example',
            type: 'POST',
            Url: "@Url.Action("Rep_Contracts", "Home")",
            id: 'ajax',
            ajaxUrl:  "@Url.Action("Rep_Contracts", "Home")",
            loadScripts: '/tab/js/load.js',
            loadStyles: ['/tab/css/test.css', '/tab/css/test2.css'],
            active: true,
            allowClose: false
        })
    });
```

the first tab works correctly ,but when click the link to open a second tab,it doesn't work.what's the problem with open the page url?

Comment: Hi Mitra, I think the issue is with the id's ( id's need to be unique)  id: 'ajax'( please check this). Regards

Comment: hi @vekay , tnx alot , The problem was solved.

Comment: You are most welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tnx to @vekay for his/her helpful comments .the problem was solved